# How to show comment submission form to logged in Wordpress users?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have somewhat of an odd request.

For Wordpress comments, people who are not logged in see name/email/URL/comment fields to fill out to submit a comment. Logged in users, on the other hand, see a message "Logged in as XXX" and comment field to fill out to submit a comment.

How can I make it so logged in users see the same thing as logged out users, i.e. logged in users see name/email/url/comment and do not see "Logged in as XXX" message?

I know this is a bit of an odd request but I have a reason for wanting to do it and any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: For those asking for more information, the reason why I want to do this is because we are caching all pages for everyone. Our website is designed so that all parts of the page are the same for logged in/out users... except for the comment form. I've tried manually inserting the HTML in place of the comment_form(); function and that works... except then plugins cannot hook into the comment form, e.g. Akismet.

Comment: > Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See **[Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)** for more info..

Comment: and besides, wordpress topics are more suited on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Updated with a bit more info.

Comment: If you are using default theme, then you can edit comments.php in your theme. There is a condition to check if user is logged in or not. Remove the condition. i.e if($user_ID): check for this line.